# Wordpress ordering doesn't work with numbers

Tags: php, wordpress

I know there is a number of answers out there about this, but they all have to do with custom post types, and meta keys. I'm wondering if there is a way to order this without having to add either of those.

**I have a list of products:**

- HP Designjet T120
- HP Designjet T1200
- HP Designjet T1300
- HP Designjet T1500
- HP Designjet T2500
- HP Designjet T3500
- HP Designjet T520
- HP Designjet T7200
- HP Designjet T790
- HP Designjet T795
- HP Designjet T920

**This is my code for ordering them:**

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu-products">
    <?php
 $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_cat' => 'hp-t-series', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

<?php
 $current_post_ID = get_the_ID();
if($post_id == $current_post_ID){
  echo '<li class="active">';
}else{
  echo '<li>';
}

$mytitle = get_the_title();
?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $mytitle; ?></a>
        </li>            

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

**I would like them to be ordered like this instead (in a way where the numbers makes sense):**

- HP Designjet T120
- HP Designjet T520
- HP Designjet T790
- HP Designjet T795
- HP Designjet T920
- HP Designjet T1200
- HP Designjet T1300
- HP Designjet T1500
- HP Designjet T2500
- HP Designjet T3500
- HP Designjet T7200

I've tried different things with array's, and string exploding, but can't seem to get the right combination.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160652/wp-query-orderby-meta-key-natural-sort

Comment: Sounds convoluted but maybe you should add another field specifically for order. Technically the system is ordering correctly as that is the proper alphabetical ordering for a string. You could write a post update hook that derives the order automatically if you don't want to admin this yourself. - or do what robert suggested

Comment: Or you can put everything to the array, sort it with natural order and than output it. http://www.php.net/natsort